# Is it possible to run a streaming map reduce job remotely on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

How can I run a Streaming Map Reduce job remotely on Azure Cluster using C#? My mappers and reducers are written either in Java or C++. The .Net C# SDK's job execution method takes JobType in input so I am unable to specify type of C++ and Java based mapper/reducer.

There is another class `StreamingProcessExecutor` which seems like appropriate for my case but no where it takes my credentials in input so I think it won't be possible to use it for remote execution.

Anyone know how to execute a streaming map reduce job remotely and programtically?

Answer (score 0):

I found a class `WebHCatHttpClient` of [.Net Hadoop SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/howto-net-libraries/#install) which can be used for this purpose. Though I am still unable to successfully run a job remotely.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute this using WebHCat.

Documentation is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+MapReduceStream)

Simply make REST calls to the endpoint below: `https://<clusterDnsName>.azurehdinsight.net/templeton/v1/mapreaduce/streaming`